# Ender 5 Plus - does not level, the Z axis goes down, always

Tags: creality-ender-5

My Ender 5 Plus (original) does not perform leveling.

After the self-leveling command, the Z axis only descends.
I have already exchanged the BLTouch three times, and the problem remains unchanged.

I bought my E5P in December, in America, to bring it to Brazil, I had to completely dismantle it.

Machine reassembled, I start work again, everything works very well.
But, one day, I made the mistake of stopping an impression (due to problems with the appearance of the piece) and, before removing the piece from the bed, I pressed the HOME command, which caused the hotend/BLTouch to rest on the printed part, forcing the whole mechanism.

Well, I changed the BLTouch and the problems really started.
When I send the leveling command, the Z-axis behaves erratically, going down instead of returning to the beginning and, with each command, it goes down more and more.

I changed the leveler again, the problem persisted, I disassembled piece by piece, wiped a general cleaning, applied a clean solution to contacts all over the electronics, reassembled, reinstalled the firmware (Version 1.71.0 KF), and everything went back to work.

Yesterday, I sent a piece for printing (PLA nozzle 1.00 mm, layer 0.36 mm, speed 100 mm/s, infill 40 %), and left for my morning walk. When I returned, there was a huge ball of melted material, adhered to the hotend, again more problems. I disassembled the entire hotend, carried out the total cleaning, reassembled it, and let's go back to work.

Leveling OK, there was a problem with the thermistor and the heating of the nozzle, I changed the thermistor and the heater cartridge (taking the opportunity, since several times the system had heating problems, when the temperature should be above 230 °C / 446 °F). Everything ready, come on...

- Leveling problem has returned.
- BLTouch exchange done, nothing done
- Loading the firmware again, nothing done
- Review of connections, nothing done

The Z-axis continues to descend, not responding to commands, and in the Pronterface the message appears:

```
Error: STOP called because of BLTouch error - restart with M999
Error: STOP called because of BLTouch error - restart with M999
```

I've already exchanged BLTouch 2 times and it didn't work out.
I have 2 inductive levelers here, maybe the solution is to install them and forget the BLTouch, or do the leveling manually.

Questions:

1. Has anyone had this kind of problem with the printer? If so, what is the solution?
2. removing the leveler and performing manual leveling, has anyone tried this? What changes in Marlin need to be made?
3. Does the replacement of the BLTouch by an inductive sensor imply in what firmware changes? Is there a tutorial about it?

I appreciate any help you can get from friends

Comment: This is practically unsolvable, there is too little information on firmware and connection of the sensor, please provide additional information.

Comment: Please [edit] the question when adding additional information and not post it as an answer

Comment: You keep saying "Leveling problem has returned", but from your story I have impression, that levelling problem always had a different source. If I can suggest something: you should learn on how to focus and narrow down the single problem, before you dismantle everything to clean or re-connect (possibly even introducing new issues). Change one thing at time, take a note, do tests, keep results, etc. I think the best idea in your text is question #2 about removing ONLY the leveler (temporary change). It would allow to check if problem is related to the BLTouch, and not Z-motor cable e.g. etc.

Comment: Possibly related: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4158/prusa-i3-z-axis-only-goes-down-even-on-up-command

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Ender 5 Plus.

There is a small set screw at the top of the BLTouch you will need to tighten this in to adjust the location of the sensor pin. Keep screwing it more and more until you see it initialize reliably that is it should move out and back twice to initialize.

When the BLTouch initializes correctly then the leveling can be completed.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. The probe for the BL touch was just stuck.

I manually pulled it out and tightened the screw and then the problem was fixed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.3DP. Could you possibly [edit] and expand upon your answer? For example, how did you pull it out, did you have to loosen the screw first? Why did it get stuck? Maybe a photo and/or a diagram would help. Please take the [tour] to see how Stack Exchange differs from other websites, and how detailed and informative answers are expected. As it stands your answer has been flagged for reasons of its brevity, which may also explain the downvote. Detailed answers usually get upvoted - have a look at other highly voted answers to get an idea of the required standard. Thanks. :-)